# Error when trying to install DeepFace on Python 3.9

Tags: python, installation, pip, deepface

I tried to install DeepFace on my Windows device, using Python 3.9, but it gives me this error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>pip install deepface
Collecting deepface
  Using cached deepface-0.0.83-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (24 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.14.0 (from deepface)
  Using cached numpy-1.26.3-cp39-cp39-win32.whl.metadata (61 kB)
Collecting pandas>=0.23.4 (from deepface)
  Using cached pandas-2.2.0.tar.gz (4.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      + meson setup C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7 C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7\.mesonpy-58bg2nid\build -Dbuildtype=release -Db_ndebug=if-release -Db_vscrt=md --vsenv --native-file=C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7\.mesonpy-58bg2nid\build\meson-python-native-file.ini
      The Meson build system
      Version: 1.2.1
      Source dir: C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7
      Build dir: C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7\.mesonpy-58bg2nid\build
      Build type: native build
      Project name: pandas
      Project version: 2.2.0

      ..\..\meson.build:2:0: ERROR: Could not parse vswhere.exe output

      A full log can be found at C:\Users\serra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dzbpz4hn\pandas_44529345be024d60848bd5ace395cfd7\.mesonpy-58bg2nid\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried doing "pip install deepface" to install the library, to no success.
Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: Try `python -m pip install deepface`

Comment: Same error, not a single difference

Comment: You don't appear to be using a virtual environment. Can you create a virtual environment and pip install deepface